# Case sensitive usage of Get-WmiObject -Filter

Tags: powershell, filter, case-sensitive, get-wmiobject

I know powershell defaults to case **in**sensitive, but in my case i need a case sensitive filtering on Wmi objects properties.

Currently I do:
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Vendor like '%MYNAME%'"`
but this also finds 'MyName' and 'myname' occurences.

How is it possible to Filter case sensitive?

I heard of the -clike filter, but it seems not to work inside those -Filter switch, e.g. `"Vendor clike '%MYNAME%'` throws an error.

I chose to use the -Filter option over the `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | where-object {...}` clause, because I read that the where-clause would transfer ALL information via network to the remote machine and THEN starts filtering.
By using the -Filter switch, only the already filtered information is transferred.

Because I use that command to obtain installed product details via remote execution on several machines, that's why I do not want to go with the Where-clause unless there is no other way.

thanks guys!

best regards
MRT

Comment: I don't think you can get around the `Where-Object` clause because the WMI Query Language the `-Filter` uses is always case-insensitive. Best option I guess is to do both: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Vendor like '%MYNAME%'" | Where-Object { $_.Vendor -clike '*MyName*' }`

Comment: Thanks, sounds nice, didn‘t think of that!